# Where is Spark table created if Hive support is not enabled?

Tags: apache-spark

Where is table created when I use SQL syntax for create table in Spark 2.*?

```
CREATE TABLE ... AS
```

Does spark store it internally somewhere of there has to always be Impala or Hive support for Spark tables to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default (when no connection specified e.g. in hive-site.xml). Spark will save it in the local metastore that is on Derby db.

And it should be stored in spark-warehouse directory in your Spark directory or whatever is defined in spark.sql.warehouse.dir prop.